# Recover password with Meteor and Mailgun

Tags: javascript, meteor, mailgun, forgot-password

I´m working in my own user account system, and it´s almost finished... but my problem right now is the recover/forgot module....

I have followed this tutorial [reset password with Meteor](http://www.meteorsnippets.com/blog/forgot-password-and-reset-password), but the mail is not sent when I submit my mail in the Forgot password form.

I´m using Mailgun as mail server. I don´t get any error by console (I get my custom message, "Email Sent. Check your mailbox.").

I think that Accounts.forgotPassword method and error function is working fine because if I try input a wrong mail, or change my process.env.MAIL_URL variable for authentication, Accounts.forgotPassword take correctly the error...but my problem is that the Forgot mail is not sent even the function say me that the mail is correctly sent.

Mail server is working fine because when I test to send a mail to my Mailgun Server by console, the mail is correctly sent.

I have checked my Mailgun Dashboard and I don´t see neither the mail sent...

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance and Happy new year!!
This is my code

**CLIENT js**

```
//config reset password
if (Accounts._resetPasswordToken) {
  Session.set('resetPassword', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
}

Template.ResetPassword.helpers({
 resetPassword: function(){
  return Session.get('resetPassword');
  }
});

Template.ResetPassword.events({
  'submit .resetPasswordForm': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var resetPasswordForm = $(e.currentTarget),
        password = resetPasswordForm.find('#resetPasswordPassword').val(),
        passwordConfirm = resetPasswordForm.find('#resetPasswordPasswordConfirm').val();
        Accounts.resetPassword(Session.get('resetPassword'), password, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('We are sorry but something went wrong.');
        } else {
          console.log('Your password has been changed. Welcome back!');
          Session.set('resetPassword', null);
        }
      });
    return false;
  }
});

Template.ForgotPassword.events({
  'submit .ForgotPasswordForm': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var forgotPasswordForm = $(e.currentTarget),
        email = forgotPasswordForm.find('#forgotPasswordEmail').val().toLowerCase();

      Accounts.forgotPassword({email: email}, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          if (err.message === 'User not found [403]') {
            console.log('This email does not exist.');
          } else {
            console.log('We are sorry but something went wrong.');
          }
        } else {
            console.log('Email Sent. Check your mailbox.');
            console.log(email);
        }
      });

    return false;
  },
});
```

**SERVER js**

```
 process.env.MAIL_URL = 'postmaster@sandbox757c0ce5316a4945a22181bb9b4060e9.mailgun.org:MyPassword@smtp.mailgun.org:587';
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="ForgotPassword">
    <div class="modal fade" id="ForgotPassword" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Recover password</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="ForgotPasswordForm" method="post">
                    <p>email: <input id="forgotPasswordEmail" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"></p> 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">Submit</button>
                    <p>Not a member yet?<a href="#" class="js-register">Join us!</a></p>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <!--<p><a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</a></p>-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <!--<button type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary js-confirm-register">Save changes</button>-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</template>

<!-- template reset password -->

<template name="ResetPassword">
    {{#if resetPassword}}
    <form  class="resetPasswordForm" method="post">
        <input id="resetPasswordPassword" name="password" placeholder="New Password" type="password" >
        <input id="resetPasswordPasswordConfirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm" type="password" >
        <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Reset">
    </form>
    <!-- end #reset-password-form -->
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

At least one problem is that the `process.env.MAIL_URL` has to be uri encoded, and needs to start with `smtp://`. Also, I had this working with the port set to 465 not 587, but I did this a while ago, so maybe try both.

Try this:

```
smtp = {
    username: 'postmaster@sandbox757c0ce5316a4945a22181bb9b4060e9.mailgun.org',
    password: 'MyPassword',
    server: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
    port: 587
}

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ouup!! I´m a dumb!!;) You save my life man!;) many thanks. it works great! the right MAIL_URL finally is  MAIL_URL = 'smtp://postmaster@sandbox757c0ce5316a4945a22181bb9b4060e9.mailgun.org:d4ba89f36403b402f5717fc5e28cb769@smtp.mailgun.org:587';